# How do planes receive their flight plan?

Tags: flight-planning

When planes land, do they receive a hardline connection to ATC in order to receive the next flight plan, or do they receive their flight planes wirelessly from ATC?

Comment: Planes receive flight plans? Or their pilots do?

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about route schedules and not "flight plans" per se.

Comment: Flight crew (pilots) receive flight *clearances* by one several means including by phone, radio, or electronic text. Unless a dispatcher is involved, the flight plan is not *received* by the flight crew; rather the flight crew *gives* the flight plan to ATC before receiving their clearance. If a dispatcher creates the flight plan, then the crew must get the flight plan from the company dispatcher, not from ATC.

Comment: Are you asking about airline operations? Flight plan submission and handling can be very different between airlines, charters and individual flights.

Comment: You don't "receive" a flight plan, you *file* a flight plans and later receive a an IFR clearance based on it.

Answer (score 9):

The airline files the flight plan to the air traffic control (ATC) on behalf of the crew. The crew receive the print out before the flight.

The *airplane* "receiving" the flight plan can then mean one of two things:

### Flight plan programming

The crew will use this printed flight plan to setup/program the [FMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_management_system) in the cockpit.

Alternatively, the airline can send the flight plan to the crew wirelessly via [ACARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Communications_Addressing_and_Reporting_System), the crew then prints it out in the cockpit.

If the route flown is frequent and rarely changes, the airline can have it saved on the plane, the crew will then load the saved plan, and revise it—making sure it matches the print out.

### It's time to get on with the flight

The crew will call ATC on radio requesting clearance to their destination as filed.

If everything matches, they get the go-ahead. If not, amendments will be relayed, and changed accordingly in the FMS.

Alternatively, the clearance can be requested digitally using the ACARS, [CPDLC-DCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller%E2%80%93pilot_data_link_communications), or in the near future, [SWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Wide_Information_Management).

---

Any digital communication is subject to airport, airline, and airplane equipment.

Comment: And to add on, at the boarding gates of some airlines, a little before the boarding starts, the pilots will go to a printer at the gate and print out the dispatch and flightplan.

Comment: You give this answer in the context of airline operations using dispatchers, but it is worth mentioning that in other contexts it will be a member of the actual flight crew that files the flight plan.

Comment: I'm not sure that we are understanding each other. My meaning is that in many cases there is no dispatcher or "airline" involved, rather it is the flight crew that files the flight plan.